# Using TCL eval command with "set"

Tags: tcl, eval

Here is the code I am testing:

```
proc check_eval {} {
    set cmd {set return_val {}; set return_val}
    puts "Command to evaluate : $cmd"
    uplevel eval $cmd
}
```

I encountered the following problem: when I am calling "check_eval", it looks like the statement "set return_val {}" is ignored. I.e., the interpeter looks for existing return_val variable in the calling scope.
Example:

```
tcl>unset return_val
tcl>check_eval
Command to evaluate : set return_val {}; set return_val
can't read "return_val": no such variable
while evaluating check_eval


tcl>set return_val 556
556
tcl>check_eval
Command to evaluate : set return_val {}; set return_val
556
tcl>
```

On the other hand, if I replace "set return_val {}" in the procedure by, for example, "set return_val 10000", it will show 10000 when running:

```
tcl>set return_val 556
556
tcl>check_eval
Command to evaluate : set return_val 10000; set return_val
10000
tcl>set return_val
10000
```

Does anybody can explain me please what is going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing two levels of evaluation/interpreting, first with `uplevel` then with `eval`, and the brace grouping around the cmd script only protects you from the first one.

You don't need `eval`, this will suffice:

```
uplevel $cmd
```

**EDIT**: Both `eval` and `uplevel` `concat`:enate all their arguments together into a flat string and evaluate it *as a script* (with `uplevel` you can choose another stack frame to run it in). They don't use the first argument as a *single command* name and the rest of the arguments as arguments to send to that command. If that was the case, you'd get an error message from your `eval` that the command "set return_val {}; set return_val" couldn't be found. So you're using `eval` correctly but `uplevel` wrong.

`uplevel` runs this script...

```
eval set return_val {}; set return_val
```

...which is broken in more ways than one, because you didn't list quote (group) it's arguments.

`eval` isn't needed in your example, but should you need to call a single command uplevel, without it's arguments getting concatenated, the way to quote static strings when you don't need any substitutions, is with braces:

```
uplevel {after 1000 {set return_val {}; set return_val}}
```

...and the way to quote dynamic strings with substituted values in it, is with `list`:

```
set cmd {set return_val {}; set return_val}
uplevel [list after 1000 $cmd]
```

Comment: @mkostya, read the ["Eval and Quoting"](http://beedub.com/book/3rd/Eval.pdf) chapter from The Book to get better understanding of the quoting issues.

Comment: Alternatively, `uplevel [list eval $cmd]`. That's totally the same as `uplevel $cmd` though, so guess which is better…

Comment: Thanks all (especially potrzebie) for your answers!